# AttributeError: 'Future' object has no attribute 'html'

Tags: python-requests-html

Using the `requests_html` library

I get an `AttributeError` exception:
`"AttributeError: 'Future' object has no attribute 'html'`

Code:

```py
asession = requests_html.AsyncHTMLSession()
r = await asession.get(link)
await r.html.arender(sleep=2, scrolldown=15)
link = link + "?page=3"
r = asession.get(link)
await r.html.html.arender(sleep=8,scrolldown=15)  # Exception is raised here
```

Comment: Do you really need to write `.html` twice? Earlier you do `await r.html.arender(sleep=2, scrolldown=15)` with just one `.html`. I suspect the problem is that typo.

Comment: The fact that you have the exact same thing 5 lines above should have given you the biggest clue.

Comment: i really try to edit .html and remove one  before posting but can't success